# Matching string using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I want to write a regular expression in a C++ program which checks if a string matches the following expression:

a word not containing '_' but it can contain number followed by

'_' followed by

three digits in a row (i.e. 047)

followed by '_' followed by

a string (can contain anything)

I have tried the following expression but it does seem to find the desired string as described above. I suspect the problem lies in the first part but I cannot detect it in order to modify properly:

```
static const wregex stringForm("([^_]?)_?(\\d{3})_(.+)");
```

What is then the proper reg expression?

Comment: Could you add a concrete example of a string you want matched?

Comment: The first to conditions contradict. "Not containing ... " vs. "can contain ... when followed by ...". This logical error reflects in your regexp.

Comment: your example does not match the above description (the description does not ask for leading underscore before 3 digits number). You should provide several examples, some matching, some not matching to maximize changes to get a usefull answer.

Comment: your example does not have "number followed by '_' followed by three digits"

Comment: @OrangeDog the first part of the string should be a word which can contain number as well, not absolutely a number.

Comment: I think you really need to re-write the question to be clearer then, with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\b[^_]*?(_\d{3}.+?)?\b
```

A word (`\b` is word boundary, quantifiers are non-greedy).
Zero or more characters that aren't _ (`[^_]*?`).
Optionally (`(...)?`), the digit sequence you described (`_\d{3}`) followed by one or more of any character (`.+?`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
static const wregex stringForm("([a-zA-Z0-9]*_[0-9]{3}.*)");
```